# Using the same index in a sum

Tags: cplex, opl

I am trying to write a simple constraint but I am probably making a basic coding mistake. I want to use the same index twice, but  the OPL gives me an error message, stating that the second index does not exist.

```
forall(i in 1..3, t in 10)
   sum(l in 1..2)
     z[i][l][t]+z[i+3][l][t]<=1;
```

I have remove the names of the parameters and replaced them with values, as i think this is a "grammatical" error and iI don't  to make the question too confusing. The OPL is underlining my second "l" index and tells me it does not exist.

I would like to have the constraint sum the z variable for all [t], in all 3 of my [i] and sum on [l], where [l] has to be the exact same value.

What would be the right way to code this constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remember operator priorities and you could solve your issue with parenthesis.

Let me give you a tiny example:

```
int a=sum(i in 1..2) 1+i;

execute
{
writeln(a);
}
```

This does not work, but this works fine:

```
int a=sum(i in 1..2) (1+i);

execute
{
writeln(a);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!